# How to get middle Pixel Color in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to take the middle pixel(center of the screen) color on screen in android code how to do it and with that color, I want to take this color from google-map and if there is red color (heavy traffic) in the map, then I want to put the mobile in silent mode automatically without interference of the user.

If you have any idea on how to get the traffic details to code, suggest me. I haven't found anything on this. So I thought about this center of the screen as the location of the user will be at the center of the screen.

**Note**: I am not using any image in this, just I want to do it from screen.

Comment: what do you mean by "middle pixel"

Comment: Center of the screen of mobile

Comment: `some action like displaying color` elaborate please .

Comment: it is still unclear what center? Do you mean single pixel at center?

Comment: and why you tagged it as `google-api`

Comment: you are doing it the wrong way!

Comment: Can you please suggest me some other way sir @MuhammadBabar

Comment: just an idea: try to search for a programatic way to take a screenshot. Then you can process the image. I know it's not the fastest solution, but if nothing else, this can work

Comment: Because google map have some layers(poi's), that are also in red color (for example a hospital has a layer with letter H colored red) so in this case you will be getting wrong heavy traffic flags!